# Is being able to access /proc/ in Linux a security breach?

Tags: linux, hardware

As a user, I can run `ls proc` and read the `/proc` directory of the hosting server and read most of the data inside it (~90%).

```
> ls /proc
1 acpi cpuinfo execdomains ioports kmsg mdstat net scsi sys uptime
21 buddyinfo crypto fb irq kpagecgroup meminfo pagetypeinfo self sysrq-trigger version
23 bus devices filesystems kallsyms kpagecount misc partitions slabinfo sysvipc version_signature
231 cgroups diskstats fs kcore kpageflags modules pressure softirqs thread-self vmallocinfo
232 cmdline dma interrupts keys loadavg mounts sched_debug stat timer_list vmstat
57 consoles driver iomem key-users locks mtrr schedstat swaps tty zoneinfo
```

Should I report it to the website owner or is it useless information about server hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/proc` is used to interact with the kernel and is required by a lot of tooling.

It is considered safe to access, the more sensitive data (eg: `/proc/[pid]/*` showing per-process information) having stricter permissions.

It is possible to further restrict permissions on `/prod/[pid]` directories using the `hidepid=n` mount-time option. (see [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages//man5/procfs.5.html) for details).

You can ask the provider to tweak this option to the strictest setting, but I would not call it a security breach.